# Yet another repeated column in hibernate mapping

Tags: java, hibernate

Hibernate is giving me the following exception

```
 org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: Pricelist column: ID_OFFER (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
```

but I really cannot find the duplicate reference to ID_OFFER. Here they are the two mapping files involved.

**Offer.hbm.xml**

```xml
<hibernate-mapping>
 <class name="Offer" table="OFFERS">
  <id name="idOffer" type="java.lang.Long">
   <column name="ID_OFFER" not-null="true" precision="10" scale="0"
    sql-type="NUMBER" unique="true"/>
   <generator class="native">
    <param name="sequence">OFFERS_SEQ</param>
   </generator>
  </id>
  <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="name" type="string">
   <column name="name" not-null="true" sql-type="VARCHAR2" unique="true"/>
  </property>
  <set name="pricelists" sort="unsorted" table="PRICELISTS">
   <key not-null="true">
    <column name="ID_OFFER" not-null="true" precision="10" scale="0" sql-type="NUMBER"/>
   </key>
   <one-to-many class="Pricelist"/>
  </set>
 </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Pricelist.hbm.xml**

```xml
<hibernate-mapping>
 <class name="Pricelist" table="PRICELISTS">
  <id name="idPricelist" type="java.lang.Long">
   <column name="ID_PRICELIST" not-null="true" precision="10" scale="0" sql-type="NUMBER"/>
   <generator class="native">
    <param name="sequence">PRICELISTS_SEQ</param>
   </generator>
  </id>
  <property name="name" type="string">
   <column length="255" name="NAME" not-null="true" sql-type="VARCHAR2"/>
  </property>
  <property name="versionMajor" type="integer">
   <column name="VERSION_MAJOR" not-null="true" precision="5" scale="0" sql-type="NUMBER"/>
  </property>
  <property name="versionMinor" type="integer">
   <column name="VERSION_MINOR" not-null="true" precision="5" scale="0" sql-type="NUMBER"/>
  </property>
  <many-to-one class="Offer" name="offer">
   <column name="ID_OFFER" not-null="true" precision="10" scale="0" sql-type="NUMBER"/>
  </many-to-one>
  <many-to-one class="PricelistStatus" name="status">
   <column name="ID_STATUS_PRICELIST" not-null="true" precision="10"
    scale="0" sql-type="NUMBER"/>
  </many-to-one>
  <property name="validFrom" type="calendar">
   <column name="INIT_TIMESTAMP" not-null="true" scale="6" sql-type="TIMESTAMP"/>
  </property>
  <property name="validUntil" type="calendar">
   <column name="END_TIMESTAMP" not-null="false" scale="6" sql-type="TIMESTAMP"/>
  </property>
 </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I am going crazy. Can anybody see where is it supposed to be duplicated the reference to the column ID_OFFER? Please note: two tables of my schema have a column named like that: OFFERS.ID_OFFER, which is the primary key of the table OFFERS and PRICELIST.ID_OFFER which has a foreign key constraint referencing, obviously, OFFERS.ID_OFFER.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot about map this column as owning side (`Offer.hbm.xml` file)

```
<set name="pricelists" sort="unsorted" table="PRICELISTS">
   <key not-null="true">
      <column name="ID_OFFER" not-null="true" precision="10" scale="0" sql-type="NUMBER"/>
   </key>
   <one-to-many class="Pricelist"/>
</set>
```

it should look like (look at `inverse="true"`):

```
<set name="pricelists" sort="unsorted" table="PRICELISTS" inverse="true">
   <key not-null="true">
      <column name="ID_OFFER" not-null="true" precision="10" scale="0" sql-type="NUMBER"/>
   </key>
   <one-to-many class="Pricelist"/>
</set>
```

Answer (score 0):

What @zxcf said, actually made the exception disappear, but made another question appear in my mind. Why doesn't the following mapping creates the same problem?

**ServiceElement.hbm.xml**

```xml
<hibernate-mapping>
 <class name="ServiceElement" table="SERVICE_ELEMENTS">
  <id name="idServiceElement" type="java.lang.Long">
   <column name="ID_SERVICE_ELEMENT" not-null="true" precision="10"
    scale="0" sql-type="NUMBER" unique="true"/>
   <generator class="native">
    <param name="sequence">SERVICE_ELEMENTS_SEQ</param>
   </generator>
  </id>
  <set name="prices" table="PRICES">
   <key>
    <column name="ID_SERVICE_ELEMENT" not-null="true" precision="10"
     scale="0" sql-type="NUMBER"/>
   </key>
   <one-to-many class="Price"/>
  </set>
 </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Price.hbm.xml**

```xml
<hibernate-mapping>
 <class name="Price" table="PRICES">
  <id name="idPrice" type="java.lang.Long">
   <column name="ID_PRICE" not-null="true" precision="10" scale="0"
    sql-type="NUMBER" unique="true"/>
   <generator class="native">
    <param name="sequence">PRICES_SEQ</param>
   </generator>
  </id>
  <many-to-one class="ServiceElement" name="serviceElement">
   <column name="ID_SERVICE_ELEMENT" not-null="true" precision="10"
    scale="0" sql-type="NUMBER"/>
  </many-to-one>
 </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Isn't it the exact same mapping? But it does not throw any exception. Here they go the DDLs:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "CE_PRICELIST"."OFFERS" 
(   "ID_OFFER" NUMBER(10,0), 
"NAME" VARCHAR2(255 CHAR));
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "CE_PRICELIST"."OFFERS_PK" ON "CE_PRICELIST"."OFFERS" ("ID_OFFER");
ALTER TABLE "CE_PRICELIST"."OFFERS" ADD CONSTRAINT "OFFERS_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID_OFFER");

CREATE TABLE "CE_PRICELIST"."PRICELISTS" 
(   "ID_PRICELIST" NUMBER(10,0), 
"ID_OFFER" NUMBER(10,0));
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "CE_PRICELIST"."PRICELISTS_PK" ON "CE_PRICELIST"."PRICELISTS" ("ID_PRICELIST");
ALTER TABLE "CE_PRICELIST"."PRICELISTS" ADD CONSTRAINT "PRICELISTS_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID_PRICELIST");
ALTER TABLE "CE_PRICELIST"."PRICELISTS" ADD CONSTRAINT "PRICELISTS_OFFER_ID_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("ID_OFFER") REFERENCES "CE_PRICELIST"."OFFERS" ("ID_OFFER") ENABLE;

CREATE TABLE "CE_PRICELIST"."SERVICE_ELEMENTS" 
(   "ID_SERVICE_ELEMENT" NUMBER(10,0));
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "CE_PRICELIST"."SERVICE_ELEMENTS_PK" ON "CE_PRICELIST"."SERVICE_ELEMENTS" ("ID_SERVICE_ELEMENT");
ALTER TABLE "CE_PRICELIST"."SERVICE_ELEMENTS" ADD CONSTRAINT "SERVICE_ELEMENTS_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID_SERVICE_ELEMENT");

CREATE TABLE "CE_PRICELIST"."PRICES" 
(   "ID_PRICE" NUMBER(10,0),  
"ID_SERVICE_ELEMENT" NUMBER(10,0));
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "CE_PRICELIST"."PRICES_PK" ON "CE_PRICELIST"."PRICES" ("ID_PRICE");
ALTER TABLE "CE_PRICELIST"."PRICES" ADD CONSTRAINT "PRICES_SERVICE_ELEMENT_ID_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("ID_SERVICE_ELEMENT")
  REFERENCES "CE_PRICELIST"."SERVICE_ELEMENTS" ("ID_SERVICE_ELEMENT") ENABLE;
```

OFFERS has a PK on ID_OFFER, which is referenced by PRICELISTS.ID_OFFER; Offer has a Set< Pricelist >;
SERVICE_ELEMENTS has a PK on ID_SERVICE_ELEMENT, which is referenced by PRICES.ID_SERVICE_ELEMENT; ServiceElement has a Set< Price >;

So why is the inverse attribute needed in one case and not in another one?

Comment: There cannot be bidirectional one-to-many mapping without using `inverse` attribute. Look again at your table, I am sure that if your schema is generated from mapping XML file, then you have two places where foreign key is stored (join table or additional column in `PRICES` table).

Comment: Well, @zxcf actually I don't think so. I edited my answer adding the DDLs of the tables. I am sure it's something I cannot see and, you know, focusing always on a thing makes you focus less...

Comment: The difference is lack of `not-null="true"` besides `<key>` (and as I checked it causes this behaviour), but honestly - I don't know Hibernate too good and I don't know what not-null besides key means..